# How to remove timer from runloop immediately

Tags: objective-c, iphone, grand-central-dispatch, nsrunloop

I have a timer triggered in 5 seconds added to global queue, though i am invalidating it after 2 seconds run loop won't terminate till 5 seconds. In the following snippet backgroundTimer is an instance var, and run is a member function. What's wrong in the following code which is blocking the run loop termination.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    _backgroundTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(run) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [ [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:_backgroundTimer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] run];

    NSLog(@"Run loop terminated");

});

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [_backgroundTimer invalidate];
    _backgroundTimer=nil;

});
```

Comment: even tried adding CFRunLoopStop([[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] getCFRunLoop]); after invalidating,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem here is that your timer is being added to a run loop on some arbitrary background thread. (i.e. the thread will have been created by GCD to service the background queue) You *can* do this, but it kind of makes no sense.

That aside, you said that what you want to have happen is for this run loop to exit, but in the documentation for the `-run` method, it says the following:

> Manually removing all known input sources and timers from the run loop
>   is not a guarantee that the run loop will exit. OS X can install and
>   remove additional input sources as needed to process requests targeted
>   at the receiver’s thread. Those sources could therefore prevent the
>   run loop from exiting.
>
> If you want the run loop to terminate, you shouldn't use this method.
>   Instead, use one of the other run methods and also check other
>   arbitrary conditions of your own, in a loop.

You will need to spin the event loop yourself if you want to exit it when the timer is invalid. For example:

```
while (_backgroundTimer.valid && [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.1]]);
```

This will exit the run loop a maximum of 0.1 (- epsilon) seconds after the timer is invalidated.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
[NSRunLoop cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(run) object:nil];
```

**Edited:**

```
-(void)run{
   if(taskComplete){
      [_backgroundtimer invalidate];   
}
```

Comment: tried it didn't work, i think cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget will cancel only those which are scheduled using performSelector method family.

Comment: i need to exit from runloop before it calls run, not during 1st iteration to run method but during subsequent iteration.

Comment: @pradeepa your code works fine have you checked it properly ? It exits timer before run method calls

Comment: it does not exit after 2 seconds it exits after 5

Comment: @pradeepa do you mean it calls run method ?

Comment: @pradeepa can you please add more description what exactly you require to achieve, May be we could find more simplistic way

Comment: I need to terminate connections to server some time after the app reaches background, so i am using the runloop to check the remaining background time. when i decide its time to terminate the connection am calling invalidate. Also i am invalidating it when app becomes active. But invalidating timer is not terminating the run loop.